# File not in directory, user re-enters file name (loop) - Python

Tags: python, loops, error-handling, ioerror

What I want to do is have it so when the user enters the file name to be opened and then read, if the file inputted is not found in the directory rather than an error message appearing on the shell it should ask the user to input the file name again.

```
print("\nEnter the name of the file you would like to encrypt, ensuring that you type .txt afterwards.")
filename = input()

try:
    sample=open(filename, 'r').read()
except IOError:
    print ("there is no such a file")
```

All the code needs to do now is just loop it so if the user still doesn't enter a file name where the file to be uploaded isn't then it should ask the user to re-enter the name of the file they want uploaded.

I only want text files to be uploaded by the way.

Thanks

Comment: Well, then check for existence before opening, if there's an error, ask for the file again.

Comment: the file may exist but it may not in the same folder for example, so how would I show that via the code

Comment: Are you asking for the full path to the file? If not, why do you suppose the user doesn't mean for that EXACT filename which doesn't exist instead of the one that does exist on some other folder?

Comment: but if it doesn't exist how would python be able to read it

Comment: It shouldn't, that why you would ask the user for a file that does exist.

Comment: no i mean the file exists but it's not in the same folder

Comment: That's the exact same thing as "the file does not exist". Do you want to check for the existence of the file in any folder inside your computer?

Comment: no it needs to be in the same folder.

Comment: Then why do you ask me about a file that might exist in another folder? I guess you better rephrase your question, add pictures of the file structura and ask CLEARLY what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use while:

```
while True:
    print("\nEnter the name of the file you would like to encrypt, ensuring that you type .txt afterwards.")
    filename = raw_input()
    try:
        sample=open(filename, 'r').read()
        if sample:
            break
    except IOError:
        print ("there is no such a file, please try again")
```

Comment: it works when the file doesn't exist, but doesn't work on an existing file

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? where do you run your script, how do you provide a file path and name to your file?

Comment: have a look at what i just posted